# css3 button, selected problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is the fiddle. Some code I am working on, essentially I want the selected button to turn Orange.

Demo below

Fiddle here > http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/veqwu/4/

Perhaps also with a notice: You Picked Button 1 in a div element. ( elsewhere on the page )

I have tried all manner of css effects, but reckon the only way is plonking this lot in an array, any suggestions

Comment: What do you mean by `selected` exactly? Hovered over? Clicked on? Something else?

Comment: as in the demo in the fiddle. 
So on page load, all buttons are white.
User clicks button 1 , it turns orange.
User clicks button 2 it turns Orange, and button 1 turns white again
etc etc etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/sje397/dXxmt/

Comment: you star ! How would I position the Selected button text in a span element using css ( I can handle the css ) its just in page, it actually deletes my footer. Works great tho, thanks... Ive been working on this for bloody hours

Comment: i.e this bit $('p').text('Selected button: ' + $(this).text());
It interferes with other button elements, can we assign it an id ?

Comment: @422 - yep, just assign the element where you want the text some id, and then use `$('#elementid').text(...)` instead (where 'elementid' is the id you choose, of course).

Comment: Hi if I wanted to display an image: like ..$('.success').html('Congratulations ' + 'images/green_tick.png');

Is this correct? or have i got syntax wrong

Comment: Have tried: $('.success').html('Congratulations ') + ('src','images/green_tick.png');    But that didnt work, lol.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/veqwu/5/

using jQuery onDomReady.

nice sje397, beat me to the punch

Comment: Excellent Sebastian, like it. will play around with your scripting for the "you chose" portion, as this may work cleaner with our code. Did notice tho, until you have released mousebutton the button stays white. Thanks for your time mate